# Getting MathJax to work with Jekyll on Github

Tags: github, jekyll, blogs, mathjax

So, I followed some tutorials to get set up with Jekyll and make it work with Mathjax so that I could write Math on my blog. And this worked beautifully on my local machine. When I was satisfied and pushed the blog to GitHub following the instructions [here](http://jmcglone.com/guides/github-pages/), I committing all files from my local box to a repository called .gitHub.io. And sure enough, my blog appeared. However, none of the Math equations seem to render correctly. What do I need to do on git to make it recognize Math?

Answer (score 1):

I had to add a _layouts folder and then copied post.html from the folder corresponding to my minima theme (you can find it by running "bundle show minima"). Then, I checked in this post.html file to GitHub and the Math rendered correctly.